# Посоветуйте API с рандомными совами

Tags: node.js, api

Единственный API, который я нашёл, это `http://pics.floofybot.moe/owl`. Он мне не подходит так как использовать я его хочу для discord.js. После некоторой проверки оказалось, что иногда он даёт ссылки, явно не подходящие для `setImage()`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

+я заметил, что там не особо много самих картинок. Они часто повторяются, что... печалит?)

В общем, если что-то знаете по этому поводу, помогите пожалуйста...

Comment: Для тех, кто не хочет/не может переходить по ссылкам (а здесь таких большинство) добавьте разъяснение, каким критериям должен удовлетворять искомый API, ибо из вашего заголовка можно понять, что вам нужно нечто, выдающее вам случайные слова в текстовом виде, однако в теле вопроса фигурируют картинки

Comment: @Kir_Antipov, я же сказал, мне нужны картинки с совами, ссылки которых удовлетворяют setImage в discord.js

Comment: Ну вот, теперь вам и вовсе нужны совы :) А если серьезно, то из этого совершенно не ясно, что вам именно нужно: на картинке должно быть одно слово? Или это должно быть облако слов? Слова через запятую? Картинка должна быть цветная? Черно-белая? Каждая буква - своим цветом? Слово должно быть написано вертикально или горизонтально? Почему вы не возьмёте генератор слов, а картинку не сгенерируете сами? И ещё сотня вопросов. В вашем тексте нет конкретики.

Comment: @Kir_Antipov мне... нужны... СОВЫ! СО-ВЫ! Сова! Не камера! Не слова! Со Ва! Owl! Рандомная картинка или гифка, которую поймёт setImage() в discord.js. Даже вопрос звучит "Посоветуйте API с рандомными СОВАМИ", где вы увидели сЛова? Даже если перейти по ссылке, которую я кинул! Кроме СОВ вы ничего не найдёте! Чем вы читали вопрос?

Comment: My bad, прошу прощения :) Мой мозг настойчиво уверял меня, что в заголовке "API рандомных слов", а не "API рандомных сов". Необычненькая у вас хотелка, однако :)

Answer (score 0):

Лично я использую либу axios для того, чтобы уже из апи использовать изображение в setImage()
(Может мой ответ не очень полезен, но просто совет)